# PHP DOM traverse HTML nodes and childnode

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, domdocument

I am using some code to pick out all the `<td>` tags from a HTML page:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) {
$array_data[ ] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

This stores the data fine in my array.

The html data being looked at is:

```
<tr>
<td>DATA 1</td>
<td><a href="12345">DATA 2</a></td>
<td>DATA 3</td> 
</tr>
```

The `$array_data` returns:

```
Array([0])=>DATA 1 [1]=>DATA 2 [2]=> DATA 3)
```

My desired output is to get code out of the `<a>` tag that is associated with the  on the page.  Desired output:

`Array([0])=>DATA 1 [1]=>12345 [2]=>DATA 2 [3]=> DATA 3)`

I think `<a>` would be called child node, I am very new to working with DOM sorry if this seems a stupid question.

I have read SO link:
[Using PHP dom to get child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726281/using-php-dom-to-get-child-elements)

I've used this code to pick out the href:

```
   foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) {
      foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node){
      $link = $node->getAttribute('href');
      echo '<br>';
      echo $link;
      }
      $array_data[ ] = $node->nodeValue;
   }
```

Any help or pointers for other reading material would be greatly appreicated!

Thanks

Comment: I posted answer to solving your problem. So why you changed question? What is your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your solution Mohammed.  I was reading other SO posts to find a solution at the same time.  Once I'd found something on the SO post I posted the updated code in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check `td` has `a` child. Select anchor tag using `getElementsByTagName()` and check the selection has content using [`length`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length) property. If the `td` has anchor in child, use [`getAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) to get `href` attribute of it.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) {
    $nodeAnchor = $node->getElementsByTagName("a");
    if ($nodeAnchor->length)
        $array_data[] = $nodeAnchor->item(0)->getAttribute("href");
    $array_data[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/Ulc3A)