# PHP DOM traverse HTML nodes for hyperlink tag

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, domdocument

I posted a SO question:
[PHP DOM traverse HTML nodes and childnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542965/php-dom-traverse-html-nodes-and-childnode)

Someone kindly gave me a solution for this.
However, the data that I'm parsing actually has several hyperlink tags as shown below:

```
<tr>
<td>DATA 1</td>
<td><a href="12345" target="_top">DATA 2</a></td>
<td><a href="other_link">DATA 3</a></td> 
</tr>
```

My desired output is to only select the `href` (e.g. '12345') for the hyperlink tag that has a target of `"_top"`.

My current code selects all the hyperlink  tags in the table.

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) {
    foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node){
       $array_href[]= $node->getAttribute('href');
    }
$array_data[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target` is just another attribute, like `href`. Get the value and compare:

```
foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node){
   if ($node->getAttribute('target') === '_top') {
       $array_href[]= $node->getAttribute('href');
   }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks Matt

Answer (score 0):

While looping through the `a` tags, create a new `if` that checks if the node contains the attribute `target` with the value of `_new`, i.e.:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) {
    foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node){
        if ($node->getAttribute('target') == '_top') {
            $array_href[] = $node->getAttribute('href');
        }
    }
    $array_data[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```